# How does the C# compiler detect in which order it has to parse the files / types?

Tags: c#, build

Sorry for the bad title but i didn't know any way to make a short question, so here is the full question:

I have a question about the C# build (compiler/parser). How is it detected in which order the files/classes have to be parsed if a class depends on an other class?

For example if you have a class A which has a property of type (class) B, i assume if you want to parse class A you would first have to parse class B in order to know which properties/methods class B has?

Because otherwise if class A is parsed first it would find the property of type B and it would be a "unknown" type if class B wasn't parsed yet and it would be unkown which properties/methods it has or even if it is a value or reference type etc

The same for derived classes or interfaces, what if class A implements a interface ISomeInterface, i would assume that the base class(es) and interfaces have to be parsed first?

But what if ISomeInterface has a property of class A, so it would be kinda recurisve how is that handled?

I don't understand how the C# compiler detects in which order it has to parse the types or am i thinking wrong about this and it doesn't actually matter in which order they are parsed?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_graph

Comment: It is a multi-pass compiler, so it builds a dependency graph (as Rufus L says) on the first pass, then parses the files and compiles them.

Comment: The compiler asks Jon Skeet

Comment: It doesn't care.  The compiler makes multiple passes.  First pass extracts all the names, object types and sizes.  Then next step is to create a memory map.  Next pass then does all the linking of names to addresses.  For complex programs with multiple modules object files are created and then the linker does the final step.

Comment: There is a good [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/02/04/how-many-passes/) by Eric Lippert describing how the C# compiler works without header files, which should give you some relevant information.